# Undefined name 'AppLocalizations'. (Documentation) after creating a new project

Tags: flutter

I created a new Flutter project and did a

```
flutter pub get
```

There are no errors from the framework except the one from `AppLocalizations` class.

> Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart'.

[image]

Another error (obviously because of the same package)

[image]

---

**NOTE:**

I have already tried:

- Restarting IDE + Invalidate Caches and Restart
- `flutter pub add flutter_gen`
- Restarting Dart Analysis Server
- Updating packages

I'm using: `Flutter 2.6.0-11.0.pre • channel dev`

Comment: Hi can you share your `pubspec.yaml` ? specifically the implementation of `flutter_intl`

Comment: does it work on flutter stable channel?

Comment: @tmaihoff I didn't test it on stable channel.

Answer (score 7):

You can expect all sorts of surprises when switching between channels (and specifically when using Dev or Master channel).

If switching to `stable` or `beta` channel (`flutter channel stable` and `flutter upgrade`) due to some reasons is not an option I'd suggest upgrading flutter (newer version might have a fix) cleaning the proj OR recreatign platform projects:

```
   flutter upgrade 
   flutter clean
   flutter create .
```

Besides, I'd stick to beta channel rather than **dev/master** - it's typically better tested and has fewer issues.

Note that in 2022 **dev** channel is no longer available leaving **master** as the most recent and least tested branch.

Answer (score 6):

`flutter_gen/gen_l10n` dir is auto generated by flutter and located in `.dart_tool`. (It's not related to the package named `flutter_gen` in `pub.dev`).

Try this,

```
flutter clean
```

then,

```
flutter pub get
```

If the `flutter_gen/gen_l10n` dir is not available yet follow the below steps.

Step 0: Make sure you have these in `pubspec.yaml`,

```yaml
flutter:
  generate: true
```

and

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter_localizations:
      sdk: flutter
```

Step 1: Comment everything related to `AppLocalization` if you can't run the app with them. (Imports & Usage)

Step 2: Now run the app.

Now the `flutter_gen/gen_l10n` folder will be generated.

Finally: Un-comment everything related to `AppLocalization`.

Every time you make changes to `.arb` files you will need to flutter get / run / hot reload / hot restart the app to update generated localization files.

Comment: `flutter_gen/gen_l10n` is already generated in the project. Sorry didn't help

Answer (score 4):

In my case anything here didn't worked. I've done all the following to resolve this issue:

First I run:

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter gen-l10n
```

Then I run:

```
 flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Then I checked if `AppLocalizations` class really generated under `.dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n`, I see it's being generated but the problem still persists then I manually imported this class with:

```
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
```

Only after this the issue was resolved. I hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

Change these lines in **pubspec.yaml** file

**From**

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

**To**

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  # Enable generation of localized Strings from arb files.
  generate: true
```

**Then run:**

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

Comment: This `generate` thing is already there in the newly created project.

Comment: Are you using some listing rules in the analysis_options.yaml? if yes could you share it?

Comment: No, no such rules. Can you tell me your Flutter version? Run `flutter --version` to find it out.